# writing long text to display on screen in android so that screen scoll down

Tags: android

I want to display text which is 2-3 pages long ,tried to use scroll view but text get cut off,i'm new in development,kindly give simple example,thanx

Comment: Please post your XML layout file..

Comment: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-draw-multiline-text-canvas-easily I think this link will helps you better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work, the trick is to get what you want to scroll inside the scrollview.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="@string/text" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 11):

In your XML, write this TextView:

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxLines="7"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="TextView"
 />
```

And in `Activity`, write this:

```
TextView txtDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetails);
txtDetails.setText("Your Text");
txtDetails.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

This will scroll the text in `TextView`. No need to write in `ScrollView`.

Comment: I was wondering why everyone was recommending a textview within a scrollview when textview can manage its own scrolling :P

Comment: It's right way to display large text.

Answer (score 4):

Text getting cut off means what is the problem you are getting. Try the following code. It works.....

using xml code:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:text="HERE I TOOK NEARLY 3-4 PAGES OF DOCUMENT. IT WORKED" />

</ScrollView>
```

If you are creating dynamically means, follow this code:
main.java:

```
oncreate()
{
    ScrollView sv=(ScrollView)findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
    TextView tv=new TextView(this);
    tv.setText("just keep the text what you want here");
    sv.addView(tv);

}
```

change your xml as the following one:

main.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" > 
</ScrollView>
```

Try this code. it works....

Comment: thanx for the code,but i' have done the same but when the text increases screen size scroll should be their to scroll down to see rest text,why it is not happen'n,pl guide me i'm new in development