# Android display long long text

Tags: android

I'm working on this case for several days. I have a file with **20 thousands lines** text to be displayed in an activity.

I use a TextView in a ScrollView to display the text. Everything goes on well except that the TextView takes `3-5 seconds` to draw the text. During this drawing time, if I want to scroll the view, I am getting ANR error

> Is there any solution to avoid the ANR warning?

Comment: Read How to Avoid ANRs https://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-anr.html#Avoiding

Comment: you can use **postDealy()** till that time use loader so that user can scroll for 5 sec

Comment: divide your loooong text into a list of paragraphs and use a `ListView` / `RecyclerView`

Comment: @Charuක ANR is not the key point of my question.

Comment: @Mrinmoy Early or later, the drawing work has to be implemented. After the delayed 5 seconds, it still can not be scrolled during the drawing period.

Comment: @pskink Thanks a lot. ListView does the work well.

Answer (score 1):

For that task I've developed a library (class) called `LongTextView`: https://github.com/metalurgus/LongTextView

*Usage:*

```
<com.metalurgus.longtextview.LongTextView 
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:gravity="left|top"
    app:maxLinesPerItem="2"
    app:text="@string/long_text"
    app:textColor="#ff0000"
    app:textSize="5dp" />
```

*How it works:*

It splits whole text into parts, and shows it as a `ListView` items using recycling, and therefore - with no UI lag and OOM due to enormous `TextView`

Comment: Yes. ListView can do this job well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the hardware acceleration as false in your manifest.xml file as mentioned here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/12118798/1649353

> Or try like this

```
View scroll = layout.findViewById(R.id.scrollView1);
scroll.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
TextView txtDetails = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtDetails);
txtDetails.setText("Your Text");
txtDetails.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

From here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11589827/6437300

Comment: It doesn't work in this case. But it is the first time I know that the TextView could scroll itself. Thanks.