# how display content in each listview iteams

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-arrayadapter

I want to display 100 essays in my app. I have created a category listview where each item is going to contains another essay listview. Like *Writing>Essay>List* of 100 Essay. From here I don't know how to display content. I want when any essay title clicked then it should display its whole answer.

Ok here is what I want  pic are in google drive to see

First Category

[https://drive.google.com/file/d/1QksjP7hzpqmVCk_Y1ctwsDMYkijDHQPt/view?usp=sharing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9BT1.jpg)

When Descriptive Essay clicked on

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NLbkrKD9c8yZb7rvapCxb-Na_lCVJf3P](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2T2eY.jpg)

When "Call no man happy" is opened

[https://drive.google.com/open?id=1XXhQT4GzYs8XqC1ZlqSPmwwC1L6-wtZ-](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5GYZc.jpg)

This what I want to make as shown in the pics

Please tell me what topic should I need to learn which will be helpful to make such type app.

**My Questions.**

First, where should I store 100 essays(300 words each essay) or need to use string resources?

when an essay title is clicked to show the answer, do I need to create fragment or activity?

I created another class `ContentDispay` wherein a layout I added 4 text view for essay title and introduction, paragraphs and conclusion. I store the data in activity to display a fixed essay activity.

But I was thinking of giving each an id and with the help of getter and setter display content. but again a question raised where should I store that long essay text where I can give them id. or is there any other way which is still I need to cover to make m app up and running.

```
public class Writing extends AppCompatActivity 
   {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.formenuitem);

    ArrayList<MenuItems> items = new ArrayList<>();

        ArrayList<MenuItems> task2Item = new ArrayList<>();



        // main items list wherein essay I added item click listener and //custom view in the array."Essay" is a title and "Solved Essay" is a description.


        items.add(new MenuItems("Essay", "Solved Essay"));

        items.add(new MenuItems("Task 1", "Solved graphs"));

        items.add(new MenuItems("More", "Solved graphs"));

        items.add(new MenuItems("ANother 1", "Solved Essay"));

        items.add(new MenuItems("ANother 1", "Solved graphs"));
```

// When clicked on the essay this is the list I want to display

Now when the crime is clicked I want to display crime essay

================================================================

```
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Crime","This essay about crime"));
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Education","This essay about Education"));
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("University","This essay about University"));
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Food","This essay about Food"));
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Games","This essay about crime"));
 task2Item.add(new MenuItems("Experience","This essay about crime"));       



ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(this,items,R.color.category_numbers);



final ListAdapter itemadapter = new ListAdapter(Writing.this,task2Item,R.color.category_numbers);


  final  ListView listView = findViewById(R.id.list);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                if(position==0){
                    listView.setAdapter(itemadapter);

            }

            listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    if (position==0){
                        Intent task2iteam = new Intent(Writing.this,ContentDisplay.class);
                        startActivity(task2iteam);

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: You want expandable listview

Comment: yes I want to expand listview of each item where there will be another list which will display answer when it is click like this.   Essay/Crime/ 250 words of essay

Comment: http://www.androidtutorialshub.com/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/ this link may help you

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/

Comment: oops sorry maybe misunderstood, not that way. Example, There is Essay Folder when u open it u see a list of text files which u can read by click. same is here Click on Essay text view which shows a list of other text view and when u click on it. it shows a lot of text. but thx for ur help

Comment: the main problem i face where to store my essay text which contains more then 300 words

Comment: Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/42557057/8101634
may help you

Comment: Please check the pic this is what i want